# how to append the list with the biggest difference between it's items

Tags: python, list, for-loop, math, max

I have a list with lists with lists and for each list in list1 the one list with the biggest difference between the numbers has to be added to a new list.

```
list1 = [ [ [3, 5], [3, 8], [4, 10] ], [ [2, 4], [4, 6], [7, 12], [12,14] ] ]
wanted_output = [ [4, 10], [7, 12] ]
```

I tried this, but don't know how to continue.

```
for item in list1:
        for pair in item:
              max_diff = pair[1] - pair[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over the inner lists, and use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a key, to specify that you want to keep the sublist with the maximum differece between its elements:

```
[max(l, key=lambda sl: abs(sl[0]-sl[1])) for l in list1]
# [[4, 10], [7, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of `max()` with a lambda and a list-comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = [ [ [3, 5], [3, 8], [4, 10] ], [ [2, 4], [4, 6], [7, 12], [12,14] ] ]
>>> [max(l, key=lambda x: abs(x[0]-x[1])) for l in list1]
[[4, 10], [7, 12]]
```

Alternatively, as a written out function using a for-loop:

```
rv = []

for l in list1:
    max_seen = -float('inf')
    max_pair = []
    for p in l:
        if abs(p[0] - p[1]) > max_seen:
            max_seen = abs(p[0] - p[1])
            max_pair = p
    rv.append(max_pair)
```

Which gives us

```
>>> rv
[[4, 10], [7, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an easy solution I think:

```
wanted_output = []
for item in list1:
    max_diff = 0
    temp = None
    for pair in item:
        if pair[1] - pair[0] > max_diff:
            max_diff = pair[1] - pair[0]
            temp = pair
    wanted_output.append(temp)
```